# myVariable(int) == 0 same as myVariable(Guid) == Guid.Empty

Tags: c#, .net, guid, uniqueidentifier, equality

I recently converted a bunch of tables PK's from `int` to `uniqueidentifier`.  Now in my code I am replacing certain checks like so:

```
if (planDiagnosisID != 0)
```

with

```
if (planDiagnosisID != Guid.Empty)
```

Where **planDiagnosisID** is an `int` in the first one and a `Guid` in the second.

Is this accurate?

Comment: Yes, it is.  I don't believe `UniqueIdentifier` will ever generate the zero-GUID, as the zero value is generally reserved for a special key value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that is correct. Guid.Empty is the default value for [Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx). It is a value type, so it can't be `null`.

Or in code

```
default(Guid) == Guid.Empty
```

Just as

```
default(int) == 0
```